# javax.naming.CommunicationException LDAP SSL InitialLdapContext

Tags: java, ldap

I have strange problem with using LDAP trough SSL. To enter app we have login window where user enters his password and username. If he enter right ones, everything works fine. But if he enters wrong one there come strange problem. I have got en error about wrong password and this is still ok. But if he again try to enter, this time a  right one password/username (without closing app) I have got following exception:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: X.X.X:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed]
```

User finally needs to restart app to enter right username/password to login.
There is block of code :

```
Hashtable<String, String> t = new Hashtable<>();
.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            t.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://x.x.x:636"); // SSL Server
            t.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
            t.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            t.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDn);
            t.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

return new InitialLdapContext(t, null);
```

Last row causes Exception as I mentioned up in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved. It was necessary to re-import Certificate after unsuccessful connection to LDAP.